# Consultar datos de la respuesta de mi servicio

Tags: angular, webservice, headers, response

Estoy tratando de sacar un dato de esta salida del response el cual sale cuando ejecuto mi aplicativo angular, pero ahora necesito capturar el campo  de la línea 1: `cdPerf`:  para realizar un condicional con el dato que sale de ese campo `cdPerf`, pero la verdad no he podido sacar el dato ya que la salida es muy diferente a las que estoy acostumbrado ya que es de tipo `map`:

```
{200: Array(2)}
 200: Array(2)
0: {cdPerf: 999 deNombre: 'Inicial'} 
1: {cdPerf: 304 deNombre: 'Ingeniero de Desarrollo'}
```

Este es mi web service creo que hay que modificarle para que reciba datos de un `map` ya que la el Backend esta hecho para devolver un `map`:

```
  urlPerfil = `${this.autPerfiles}`;
  perfiles(usuario: string){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'usuario': usuario })
   const body = {usuario: String};
    return this.http.post<InterAuthPerfiles[]>(this.urlPerfil, body, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(
         map( resp => { resp          
          console.log(resp)
          return resp;
         
                       
         }),  
         catchError( err => of(false) )   
         );
  }
```

Este es mi archivo TS, el cual realiza el llamado a mi web service enviando el usuario con cual es el perfil el cual cuando lo ejecuto saca los datos de mi primera línea de código:

```
 this.authService.perfiles(this.miFormulario.value.usuario).subscribe({
            next:(resp) => {
             
               console.log(resp);
```

Estos son los datos de mi interfaz, creo que hay que cambiar esta interfaz par para que se adapte al dato del response.

```
export interface InterAuthPerfiles {
    usuario:  string;
    cdPerf:   string;
    ok?: any;    
    
}
```

he realizado muchas consultas pero pero hasta ahora ninguna me ha funcionado envío algunas de las consultas que he realizado las cuales ninguna ha salido con éxito hasta ahora la verdad no se si hay que cambiar algún dato de mi código o simplemente mejorando alguna de las consultas de abajo podría funcionar.

```
console.log(resp.'200'[1]) 
console.log(resp["200"][1])
console.log(resp.200.['1']);     
console.log(200[1].cdPerf)
```

Comment: No me manejo mucho en Angular, pero creo que estas confundiendo conceptos que hacen que tu pregunta no se entienda. Hasta donde yo entiendo no hay "tipo map" y el backend tampoco te puede devolver un map. El `map` que se ve en tu código es una función de la librería RxJS,. Otra cosa que me genera dudas es la primera salida que muestras, esto es lo que te arroja el `console.log` ??

Comment: Hola.  la salida m me genera este response.              {200: Array(2)}
 200: Array(2)
0: {cdPerf: 999 deNombre: 'Inicial'} 
1: {cdPerf: 304 deNombre: 'Ingeniero de Desarrollo'}

Comment: Supongo que es el console.log del primer código.  Prueba 2 cosas: 1) saca el `map` , es decir deja el pipe así `.pipe(catchError(err => of(false)));`, si esto no funciona, prueba 2)  donde tienes `map( resp => { resp ` ese segundo `resp` elimínalo y me dices si tienes la misma salida o no

Comment: Saca el mismo resultado.          {200: Array(2)}
 200: Array(2)
0: {cdPerf: 999 deNombre: 'Inicial'} 
1: {cdPerf: 304 deNombre: 'Ingeniero de Desarrollo'}

Comment: Haber hagamos otra prueba, coloca `.pipe(map(resp => resp.map(a => { console.log(a); return a; })),catchError(err => of(false)));`  (ojo con las llaves y paréntesis que se me puede haber pasado alguno, que lo escribí a pelo)

Comment: ahora solo imprime true

Comment: Ahora me sale solo la palabra true

Comment: Usas conceptos que no tienen que ver y sigues teniendo cosas sin sentido en el código, como te va a regresar un `map` el backend? Si muestras una respuesta JSON.  Luego los `console.log` parecen estar hechos al azar. Empieza por leer [Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: ok gracias, voy a leer ese documento.